# How to (efficiently) reposition KineticJS-shapes after window was resized?

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I am currently using KineticJS for a window-filling Canvas-application. The canvas contains several shapes that are positioned mostly in relation to the center of the screen, although several other shapes will come that will be positioned on the edges of the screen.

Calculating all those coordinates the first time the page is displayed is not a problem, but I haven't found a way to handle the shape-coordinates after/when the window is resized.

Via jQuery, the stage and it's layers are being resized when the window is resized, but since this doesn't change the coordinates of the shapes, former centered items aren't centered anymore.

Do I really need to loop through every single shape and recalculate their coordinates? Not trivial, since they are calculated with different formulas.

Sidenote, I implemented the same application with direct access to Canvas (= w/o KineticJS) and handled the resize just by re-rendering the whole canvas ;) Since the render method included the coordinate-calculation, everything was always at the correct position.

Comment: you'd stick to what's working for what you want.

Comment: Well.. unfortunately the manual/direct way doesn't give me comfortable event handling etc., so I'd rather continue migrating to kineicjs ;) can't imagine that a basic thing like resizing a window presents such a big problem :)

Comment: why don't you just scale the entire stage in kineticjs, that way no recalculation is necessary. check out this planetary orbit resizer i made: 'cs.neiu.edu/~tsam/planets' (drag the sun to resize). This uses scale, rather than recalculating positions. The same kind of logic could be applied to window size and scaling the stage when the window is resized

Comment: Since I use several raster-based images, resizing would scale those images and decrease their sharpness. Apart from that, the room around my shapes should stay free for other elements ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by defining offsets for all of my layers and recalculating those offsets after a window-resize occured. Albeit not perfect, calculating 8 values (4 * x+y) is far better than calculating hundreds.

If anyone knows an even better solution, I'd still be interested. ;)